# How to retrieve data from array using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

How to retrieve data from array by selecting a particular customer to show on UI by using angular JS? Suppose we have customer array where customer details contain(like name, email, phone etc). Now I want to select a particular customer to get all information that shows in customer corresponding UI.

This is the view:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS56d.png)
Left side shows the list of the customers and I want to select any single customer and after selecting any customer all required field must be fill dynamically by retrieving data from array of controller.

Comment: Please provide code to accompany your answer. In this case, at the very least, provide the array you are describing.

Comment: Customer corresponding UI refers to input field(TextField).

Comment: Okay. You need to provide your view, controller, and object. This question does not provide the basic information required for someone to properly answer this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that, in a single page, in left side, you have a list of customers and once a customer is clicked, you have to show its information in right side.
if you have an array like this in customerse

```
{[
    {id:1, name: "John Doe", email: "example1@domain.com", phone: "00000"},
    {id:2, name: "Johnny Doe", email: "example2@domain.com", phone: "11111"},
    {id:3, name: "John Roe", email: "example3@domain.com", phone: "22222"},
]}
```

In your html for left side, you have used ng-repeat to list the customers, here use ng-click and store it in another variable - something like following.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-click="viewCustomer = customer;">
       {{customer.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use that varible (viewCustomer) to fill the form displayed in right side. Some thing like below.

```
<form name="customerForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="viewCustomer.name">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="viewCustomer.email">
    <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="viewCustomer.phone">
</form>
```

The viewCustomer will be available in your controller in $scope.viewCustomer, so you can use it to save the changes made on the form.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks Paulson Peter for you appropriate answer.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think it helped, Please accept the answer and up vote.